# How Override Yii Framework's config/console.php with Local Console Configuration File?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

Yii framework's config/main.php file [can be overwritten](http://www.markdeepwell.com/2011/06/how-to-add-local-config-variables-to-yii/) by a local.php configuration file via an array_merge. This allows me to set different database connections and other parameters specific to production, QA, and development environments.

Yii also allows me to [run commands in the command line](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console). It uses a config/console.php file. Is there a way I can set up a local console config file in the same way that will override the main console config depending on the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that's an interesting way of doing overriding the config.  But it looks like you could just modify console.php in the same way you did the main.php (add local_config function to console.php and point it to console-local.php).

Comment: It works. Someone on my team said he couldn't do it. I took this at face value. Turns out he wasn't array merging in the config file but from the Yii bootstrap index.php file which only runs via HTTP requests. I didn't apply the same method to the console.

Comment: It's also helpful to have multiple db.php files (db_local.php, db_office.php) so you can switch between them manually with cp -f db_local.php db.php, and then put `'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/db.php'),` in your main.php. Then each user can do a `bzr/svn/git ignore db.php` (after the initial checkout, of course) and their custom db connection (and passwords) won't corrupt the master copy, and they won't be uploading their local db passwords to the cloud.

Comment: or use the Environment extension: www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-environment/‎